# Any way to stop warnings from showing in a specific package - FDT / Eclipse

Tags: flash, eclipse, actionscript-3, fdt

I'm using FDT and Flash 10, and have just discovered [Flixel](http://flixel.org/), but when I import the source into my classes directory I get loads of errors and warnings.

I have fixed the errors, after reading this [post](http://flixel.org/forums/index.php?topic=185.0;prev_next=prev), but I still have a lot of warnings left.

Is there any way to stop FDT from giving me warnings on a specific package? I guess Eclipse would have the same option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an own source folder for the flixel library and go to the `Source` tab in the `FDT Build Path`. There you can uncheck `Generate Problems/Tasks` for the flixel source folder.